# Error: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, lightning, rest-api, controller, json

I have a requirement where the data from external system is fetched and upserted back in Salesforce.

below is my apex class:

```
public class RESTClass {
    @future(callout=true)
    
    public static void RESTClass() {   
        
        String jsonbody = '{ ' +
            '"username": "<username>",' +
            '"password": "<password>"' +
            '}' ;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        req.setEndpoint('<user auth endpoint>');
        req.setBody(jsonBody);   
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        String response = res.getBody();
        UserAuthJSONParser jsondes = (UserAuthJSONParser) JSON.deserialize(response, UserAuthJSONParser.class);
        HttpRequest policyreq = new HttpRequest();
        policyreq.setMethod('GET');
        policyreq.setTimeout(120000);
        policyreq.setEndpoint('<main endpoint>'); 
        policyreq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jsondes.value.token);
        Http policyhttp = new Http();
        HTTPResponse policyres = policyhttp.send(policyreq);
        String policyresponse = policyres.getBody();
        
        JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(policyresponse, JsonParser.class);
        
        JsonParser.cls_value clsValue = objJsonParser.value;
        Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data> clsDataMap = new Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data>();
        
      
        for(JsonParser.cls_data objClsData: clsValue.data){
            clsDataMap.put(objClsData.id, objClsData);
        }
        list<policy__c> updatelist = new list<policy__c>();
        
      
        for (String eachIdFromMap : clsDataMap.keySet()){
            
            policy__c policy = new policy__c(
                unique_id__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).id,
                policy_date__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policydDate);
            updatelist.add(policy);  
        }
        upsert updatelist unique_id__c;
    }    
    
}
```

Now, from the line `clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policydDate`, I am getting the error as

> System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Even though I have null checked that line as follows, I could see the same error.

```
string poldate;
if(String.isNotBlank(clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policyDate)){
               poldate = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policyDate;
            }
```

Below is the debug log of poldate:

[image: poldate]
From the above debug log, few rows have values and few are having null.

Can anyone please suggest any changes to the above logic so that I can get this error resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: It probably is your eachIdFromMap variable that is null, I'd check it first...

Comment: It has values and other fields are getting updated. But for policyDate, there are few rows which are null and which has values. and that is causing problem here. Is there any way to null check that?

Comment: Where is your error when you check ? Is it on the line "poldate = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policyDate;", is it on the line where you create the new policy__c, or is it on the update statement line ? Just to be sure, can you change your line "policy_date__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policydDate " to "policy_date__c = (eachIdFromMap!=null) ?  clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policydDate : null" ? Are there triggers on you policy__c object ? Did you try to check the log in the developer console ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO, no there are no triggers and the error is from line poldate = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policyDate. 
As suggested, even though I have updated the line to policy_date__c = (eachIdFromMap!=null) ? clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policydDate : null, I am seeing the error. Few rows have values and few have value as null. Wondering what is the issue behing this error

Comment: Well I can't see any other reason for this error, the message says the argument is null and there is only one function call in your line and it's Map.get, the argument being eachIdFromMap. Maybe I'm wrong but if you wanna try a last thing to be sure I am : String poldate; if (eachIdFromMap == null) System.debug('eachIdFromMap was null'); else poldate = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policyDate; Then check the logs, if error is still there I have no more idea...

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace? And that is not how you check null in maps . First you check if your map contains key , then check if the key contains the value, then check if the value has the required parameter. `clsDataMap.containsKey(eachIdFromMap) && clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap) != null && clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).policyDate != null`

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO, I have updated my question with debug log. Could you please check that

Comment: That just tells us you have some null or empty string or only spaces string values in your Map. So apparently I was wrong you have no null key in the Map (that can happen when you deserialize json to a Map). However there's no reason for a NullPointerException to be raised when you affect null to a SObject field. You have to read your logs, find the exception, go back up to the previous METHOD_ENTRY line to see in which method you were when exception rose, and then down again to see the line number just before the exception...